# Syntax highlighting for own functions only for certain symbols

Tags: functions, front-end, symbols, syntax-highlighting

For simplicity, let's say I have defined my own function `f` that takes in exactly one input argument which is of the `Symbol` type like this:

```
f[x_Symbol]:=x;
```

Now, I want the input argument to show up with Syntax highlighting (with the colouring on symbols like in `D[]` or `Plot[]`) for certain input symbols when I call the function.

Let's say I want the green-ish syntax colouring to show up when the input argument is either `a`,`b`, or `c`. Colouring for other symbols can stay as it is (i.e. blue).

How do I achieve this? (The attached picture is what I want to achieve.)

> [image: example colouring]

Note: I am using Mathematica version 12.2.

Comment: Not possible with current Mathematica front-end. Email WRI to request they add better support for stuff like this. As a work-around, you _can_ add autocompletion support for string arguments, if you're willing to use strings to denote the special supported functions.